# Will Task.WhenAll perform tasks simultaneously if possible?

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

I mean if I have two tasks `async Task<Data1> GetData1Async()` and `async Task<Data2> GetData2Async()` and doing something in this way:

```
var getTask1 = GetData1Async();
var getTask2 = GetData2Async();

await Task.WhenAll(getTask1, getTask2);

var result1 = getTask1.Result;
var result2 = getTask2.Result;
```

Is there's any chance for `GetData1Async` and `GetData2Async` to work in parallel?

Comment: They will run simultaneously. What do you mean by "work in parallel"?

Comment: They will work in parallel, if you mean that they will run concurrently / simultaneously / at the same time.

Comment: What makes you think it is not happening right now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Task.WhenAll` just awaits the two tasks, does not run them.

If the two methods `GetDataXAsync`are truly asynchronous, and by the time `Task.WhenAll` is called they did not finish yet, then yes, they will be executing in parallel.

Comment: Am I understanding it right, that doing `GetData1Async()` performs call and next `GetData2Async()` will call right after that without waiting for `GetData1Async()` to finish and then `Task.WhenAll` just waits them all to finish their parallel work?

Comment: @TrolltheLegacy Yes